# EMulator not showing full display

Tags: android, emulation

My emulator ashow the app in half screen sest in blackcolor oly
Why it is showing like this but in some other emulator it shows perfectly.. i set the layouts height to fill parent only but still its not showing fully

Comment: Add the image, provide more information and clean your question.

Comment: i am new to stack overflow so its not allowing me to add image

Comment: Upload the image somewhere else and link to it here.

Comment: my screen is displayed correctly but it is not exactly fit to the screen in height .. some spacing is there (as like we have given margin values.. but i never giver that)

Comment: http://imageupload.org/en/file/21926

this s the image of my emulator

Comment: @Dinu it is saying 404 not found

Comment: sorry this works http://imageupload.org/en/file/219264/abc.png.html

Comment: Is it just your app? It sounds like a problem with your layout.

Comment: but i have the master layout height as fill parent and the child layouts height as fill parent oly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the skin i use to the emulator. for that i used this in my manifest file

```
  <supports-screens android:resizeable="false" 
    android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```